# Ansible Add LDAP user to local group

Tags: ansible

Writing a playbook to add a LDAP user to a local group.

```
---
- hosts: hostname
  tasks:
    name: Add user to local group
    groups: wheel
    append: yes
```

Looks like user module does not work for adding LDAP user to local group.

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "usermod: Permission denied.\nusermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n", "name": "user1", "rc":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this task with privilege.. Enable become: true

```
---
- hosts: hostname
  tasks:
   - name: Add user to local group
     user:
       name: james
       groups: wheel
       append: yes
     become: true
```

here is the documentation for [Understanding privilege escalation: become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)

Comment: You are right.  I just forget to escalate privilege. Thank you!